# Display Image By ID in MEAN

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean

I am trying to store image in mongoDB  and retrieve it back to display from Angular side.

**profile.html**

```
<input class="file-hide" type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" 
 placeholder="Upload file..." />
 <button type="button" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
```

**profile.component.ts**

```
images=[];
    fileChangeEvent(event) {
        this.profileService.uploadAvatar(event); 
       }

      getImage() {
        this.patientService.getImage().subscribe(
          data => this.images = [data],
          error => console.log(error),
        );
      }
```

**profile.service.ts**

```
    uploadAvatar(event){
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
     let file: File = fileList[0];
     let formData:FormData = new FormData();
     formData.append('avatar', file, file.name);
     let headers = new Headers();
     /** No need to include Content-Type in Angular 4 */
     // headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
     // headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

      this.http.post('/api/images', formData)
         .subscribe(
             data => console.log('success'),
             error => console.log(error)
         )
   }

}
getImage(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`/api/images/:id`);
}
```

**Server Side**

```
  app.post(/images,(req, res, next) => {
  upload(req, res, function(err) {
  // Create a new image model and fill the properties
  let newImage = new Image();
  newImage.filename = req.file.filename;
  newImage.originalName = req.file.originalname;
  newImage.desc = req.body.desc
  newImage.save(err => {
      if (err) {
          return res.sendStatus(400);
      }
      res.status(201).send({ newImage });
      console.log("uploaded")
  });
})
});

app.get(/images,  (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Get Image By Id")
  let imgId = req.params.id;

  Image.findById(imgId, (err, image) => {
      if (err) {
          res.sendStatus(400);
      }

      // stream the image back by loading the file
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');

      fs.createReadStream(path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, image.filename)).pipe(res);

  })
});
```

**Model**

```
export interface IImageModel extends mongoose.Document {
    filename: string; 
    originalName: string; 
    desc: string;
    created: Date;
    url : String
  };

  // Actual DB model
export var imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    filename: String,
    originalName: String,
    desc: String,
    url : String,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
 export const Image = mongoose.model<IImageModel>('Image', imageSchema);
```

Now I can upload file from my front end and it's storing in database. I can view image by ID using postman. But I want to display the image from  my front end side. I am struck with that. Can any one help me with displaying image that is stored in mongoDB.[image: can view image using postman]

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(data)` inside the `this.patientService.getImage()` ?
Are you getting a image file or a base64 value?

Comment: getting some error in console like error context.  I am not sure about that this.patientService.getImage(), because i got the reference from internet. It will be good, if you guide me from that get method

Comment: Change the method like this nad give me the output

getImage() {
        this.patientService.getImage().subscribe(( data) =>{ 
          this.images = [data];
         console.log(data);
},
          error => console.log(error);
        );
      }

Comment: context error :(

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the Image by using id then you need get the id from data base before you fetch the data from data base. change your code like this it will work

```
 uploadAvatar(event){
        let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
        if(fileList.length > 0) {
         let file: File = fileList[0];
         let formData:FormData = new FormData();
         formData.append('avatar', file, file.name);
         let headers = new Headers();
         /** No need to include Content-Type in Angular 4 */
         // headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
         // headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');


// Once you post the image you will get the back the id
          this.http.post('/api/images', formData)
             .subscribe((img)
                   this.getImage(img.id);
                 data => console.log('success'),
                 error => console.log(error)
             )
       }

    }

    getImage(id): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(`/api/images/:id`,{responseType:'blob'});
    }
```

Comment: How to display it in angular side?

Comment: what response are you getting back?

Comment: HttpErrorResponse
error
:
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at Object.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHt…, text: "����C↵
 ↵↵

…+�9�ڷ�"�q����X�{�?߄�Silֹ�k��ƶ�����؎1�m/��"}
headers
:
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
:
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/api/images"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
url
:
"http://localhost:4200/api/images"
__proto__
:
HttpResponseBase

Comment: can you share the screeshot

Answer (score 0):

Here is the screenshot of the error [image: error message]

Comment: can you add the response type with your get request it will fix the issue